# Pressing a GUI button that picks a random word from an array and places it on a JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I have a question about this *GUI* code. How to show up on the `JLabel` the random words?

Basically the purpose of this program is to create a *GUI* button that when clicked selects a random word from an array and places it into a `JLabel`.

What I'm having trouble with is getting the words to show up on the `JLabel`, I'm not quite sure how it should be done.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GuiQuiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        JPanel subPanel1 = new JPanel();
        subPanel1.setBackground(new Color(134, 179, 0));
        subPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
        subPanel1.add(new JLabel("Random word here"));

        String[] names = { "Class", "Charger", "Pencil", "Dog", "Robot", "Ninja", "Teacher", "Video", "Book",
            "Computer" };


        JButton button = new JButton("Generates a random word");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String name = names[(int) (Math.random() * names.length)]; 
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText(name);
            }
        });

        mainPanel.add(button);
        mainPanel.add(subPanel1);


        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question you have?

Comment: JLabel,setText("My text");

Comment: Progman how can I add the random word chosen by the array into the JLabel when the button is pressed?

Comment: Tip: Add @Progman or whoever you're replying to, to notify them (The `@` is important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're declaring an anonymous `JLabel` when writing:

   ```
   subPanel1.add(new JLabel("Random word here"));
   ```

   You need to set it to a variable:

   ```
   JLabel label = new JLabel("Random word here");
   subPanel1.add(label);
   ```
2. Right now you have your `button` have its own `ActionListener`:

   ```
   button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           String name = names[(int) (Math.random() * names.length)]; 
           ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText(name);
       }
   });
   ```

   And you're setting the `JButton`'s text, not the label, so we need to change that as:

   ```
   button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           String name = names[(int) (Math.random() * names.length)]; 
           label.setText(name);
       }
   });
   ```

That should do what you're trying to do, I haven't tried it but it works in my mind.

---

Additional tips:

- Don't call `setPreferredSize()`, instead override `getPreferredSize()` methods: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)
- Don't leave that much space in the middle of the code and indent it correctly.

Comment: If the answer solved your question be sure to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @Luis